# Calculating mean of a large data frame for each row based on last 15 minutes

Tags: r, dataframe, time, apply, lubridate

I have a data frame such as:

```r
data <- data.frame("date" = c("2015-05-01 14:12:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:14:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:15:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:42:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:52:57"), 
                   "Var1" = c(2,3,4,2,1),
                   "Var2" = c(0.53,0.3,0.34,0.12,0.91),
                   "Var3" = c(1,1,1,1,1))

data

                 date Var1 Var2 Var3
1 2015-05-01 14:12:57    2 0.53    1
2 2015-05-01 14:14:57    3 0.30    1
3 2015-05-01 14:15:57    4 0.34    1
4 2015-05-01 14:42:57    2 0.12    1
5 2015-05-01 14:52:57    1 0.91    1
```

However, actually with **60,000 rows and 26 variables!**

What I want to achieve is this:

```r
       unix_timestamp Var1  Var2 Var3
1 2015-05-01 14:12:57  2.0 0.530    1
2 2015-05-01 14:14:57  2.5 0.415    2
3 2015-05-01 14:15:57  3.0 0.390    3
4 2015-05-01 14:42:57  2.0 0.120    1
5 2015-05-01 14:52:57  1.5 0.515    2
```

In theory: 
**Calculate for each row of data the mean (for Var1 and Var2 and sum for Var3) based on the observations of the last 15 minutes.**

I came up with:

```r
library(lubridate)

data <- data.frame("date" = c("2015-05-01 14:12:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:14:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:15:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:42:57", 
                                        "2015-05-01 14:52:57"), 
                   "Var1" = c(2,3,4,2,1),
                   "Var2" = c(0.53,0.3,0.34,0.12,0.91),
                   "Var3" = c(1,1,1,1,1))

pre <- vector("list", nrow(data))

for (i in 1:length(pre)) {
  #to see progress
  print(paste(i, "of", nrow(data), sep = " "))

  help <- data[as.POSIXct(data[,1]) > (as.POSIXct(data[i,1]) - minutes(15)) & 
                 as.POSIXct(data[,1]) <= as.POSIXct(data[i,1]),] # Help data frame with time frame selection


  chunk <- data.frame("unix_timestamp" = as.POSIXct(data[i,1]), 
                      "Var1" = mean(help$Var1),
                      "Var2" = mean(help$Var2),
                      "Var3" = sum(help$Var3))
  pre[[i]] <- chunk
}

output <- do.call(rbind, pre)
output
```

...what actually returns the desired result. However, this does not work or takes 100 years for a dataframe that has 60,000 rows (Don't forget I've actually 26 variables).

Does anyone has an idea how I can get rid of the loop or how can I tune my function? Would by so grateful! I also experimented with sapply but it seems that it is not much faster or I did something wrong.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we could convert `date` to `POSIXct` class, use `cut` to break it down into 15 minute intervals and then take cumulative mean and sum of respective columns.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(group = cut(as.POSIXct(date), breaks = "15 mins")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Var1, Var2), cummean) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Var3), cumsum) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#  date                 Var1  Var2  Var3
#  <fct>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2015-05-01 14:12:57   2   0.53      1
#2 2015-05-01 14:14:57   2.5 0.415     2
#3 2015-05-01 14:15:57   3   0.39      3
#4 2015-05-01 14:42:57   2   0.12      1
#5 2015-05-01 14:52:57   1.5 0.515     2
```

Using `mutate_at` since there are 26 variables so that we can apply the same function to multiple columns at once.

**EDIT**

Based on @Rentrop's comment updating the answer using his data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dat %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date), 
         Var1 = map_dbl(date, ~mean(Var1[date >= (.x - (15 * 60)) & date <= .x])), 
         Var2 = map_dbl(date, ~mean(Var2[date >= (.x - (15 * 60)) & date <= .x])), 
         Var3 = map_dbl(date, ~sum(Var3[date >= (.x - (15 * 60)) & date <= .x])))


#                date Var1  Var2 Var3
#1 2015-05-01 14:12:57  2.0 0.530    1
#2 2015-05-01 14:14:57  2.5 0.415    2
#3 2015-05-01 14:29:57  3.5 0.320    2
#4 2015-05-01 14:42:57  3.0 0.230    2
#5 2015-05-01 14:52:57  1.5 0.515    2
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! Tailored it to my real df and I think this is exactly what I searched for. So grateful!

Answer (score 3):

Changing the third input time from `14:15` to `14:29`

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)
dat <- data.frame("date" = c("2015-05-01 14:12:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:14:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:29:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:42:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:52:57"), 
                   "Var1" = c(2,3,4,2,1),
                   "Var2" = c(0.53,0.3,0.34,0.12,0.91),
                   "Var3" = c(1,1,1,1,1))
```

You can do the following

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, tz = ""))
in_15 <- map(dat[["date"]], ~between(dat[["date"]], left = .x - minutes(15), right = .x))
map_df(in_15, ~filter(dat, .x) %>% 
      summarise(date = last(date), Var1 = mean(Var1), Var2 = mean(Var2), Var3 = sum(Var3)))
```

which results in

```
                date Var1  Var2 Var3
1 2015-05-01 14:12:57  2.0 0.530    1
2 2015-05-01 14:14:57  2.5 0.415    2
3 2015-05-01 14:29:57  3.5 0.320    2
4 2015-05-01 14:42:57  3.0 0.230    2
5 2015-05-01 14:52:57  1.5 0.515    2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess that also works but I go with Ronaks solution because the syntax is for me as a R-Newbie more familar! Anyway thanks a lot for talking time!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution using `non-equi` joins and aggregation with `.EACHI`.

```
setDT(data)
data[, date := as.POSIXct(date)]
data[, date_min := date - 15*60]

data[data, on = .(date >= date_min
                  , date <= date)
     , .(mean(Var1), mean(Var2), sum(Var3))
     , allow.cartesian = T
     , by = .EACHI
     ][, date:= NULL][]

                  date  V1    V2 V3
1: 2015-05-01 14:12:57 2.0 0.530  1
2: 2015-05-01 14:14:57 2.5 0.415  2
3: 2015-05-01 14:15:57 3.0 0.390  3
4: 2015-05-01 14:42:57 2.0 0.120  1
5: 2015-05-01 14:52:57 1.5 0.515  2
```

Performance: @Ronak has the best performance with his `purrr` solution.

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
       cole_dt  5.0338  5.40155  5.904821  5.63355  5.81995 21.6485   100
   ronak_dplyr  6.4104  6.51575  6.764089  6.60685  6.76455 11.8158   100
   ronak_purrr  3.3591  3.42850  3.629899  3.50465  3.59220  6.6374   100
 rentrop_purrr 17.6355 17.95750 18.832567 18.09150 18.77765 30.9068   100
```

Code for reproducibility:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

data <- data.frame("date" = c("2015-05-01 14:12:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:14:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:29:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:42:57", 
                              "2015-05-01 14:52:57"), 
                   "Var1" = c(2,3,4,2,1),
                   "Var2" = c(0.53,0.3,0.34,0.12,0.91),
                   "Var3" = c(1,1,1,1,1))

dt <- as.data.table(data)

microbenchmark(
  cole_dt = {
    dt1 <- copy(dt)

    dt1[, date := as.POSIXct(date)]
    dt1[, date_min := date - 15*60]

    dt1[dt1, on = .(date >= date_min
                      , date <= date)
         , .(mean(Var1), mean(Var2), sum(Var3))
         , allow.cartesian = T
         , by = .EACHI
         ][, date:= NULL][]
  }
  , ronak_dplyr = {
    data %>%
      group_by(group = cut(as.POSIXct(date), breaks = "15 mins")) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(Var1, Var2), cummean) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(Var3), cumsum) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-group)
  }
  , ronak_purrr = {
    data %>%
      mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date), 
             Var1 = map_dbl(date, ~mean(Var1[date >= (.x - (15 * 60)) & date <= .x])), 
             Var2 = map_dbl(date, ~mean(Var2[date >= (.x - (15 * 60)) & date <= .x])), 
             Var3 = map_dbl(date, ~sum(Var3[date >= (.x - (15 * 60)) & date <= .x])))

  }
  , rentrop_purrr = {
    dat <- data %>% mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, tz = ""))
    in_15 <- map(dat[["date"]], ~between(dat[["date"]], left = .x - minutes(15), right = .x))
    map_df(in_15, ~filter(dat, .x) %>% 
             summarise(date = last(date), Var1 = mean(Var1), Var2 = mean(Var2), Var3 = sum(Var3)))
  }
)
```